# A Connect Wall to start the day and motivate you

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be separated into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a word absent from the wall which can be placed in all four of those groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANON | BOARD | CANDY | CLOCK |
| CRAZY | DRUG | DRUNK | MARCH |
| OAKEN | RAVEN | ROCK | SIZE |
| TAKE | TIME | TOUCH | VAT |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What new word can be placed in all four of those groups?**

Hint:

> One of the categories is stuck in 2011, **with an actor who would peak in a later year by singing with a Stone**

Hint 2:

> One of the categories can be of noble descent, **the head of its members can be replaced with more noble ones**

Hint 3:

> One of the categories doesn't start soft, **the members would love some extra strength to help them**

Hint 4:

> One of the categories goes further than needed, **but maybe too much**

Hint 5:
All previous hints now have additional **bold** text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a hat-tip to Rand al'Thor for identifying two of the connecting categories, I believe the connecting wall can be resolved as follows:

> **Group 1:** Words that can be preceded by 'OVER'
>  (thanks @Rand)
>
>  Over**TAKE**
>  Over**BOARD**
>  Over**SIZE**
>  [Over**CLOCK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overclocking)
>
>  **Group 2:** Words that can be preceded by 'HARD'
>  (thanks @Rand)
>
>  Hard **ROCK**
>  Hard **TIME**
>  Hard **CANDY**
>  Hard **DRUG**
>
>  **Group 3:** Replace initial letter with Periodic Table symbol for a noble gas
>
>  **ANON** → **Xe**NON
>  **RAVEN** → **He**AVEN
>  **OAKEN** → **Kr**AKEN
>  **VAT** → **Ne**AT
>
>  **Group 4:** Words in the titles of [2011 Ryan Gosling movies/TV shows](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0331516/)
>
>  **CRAZY**, Stupid, Love
>  **DRUNK** History
>  The Ides of **MARCH**
>  [**TOUCH** of Evil](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2167961/)

This means that the overall connection for the wall is:

> **DRIVE** - a word with relevance to the title (think 'get up and go') and which satisfies all four group connections:
>
>  Over**DRIVE**
>  Hard **DRIVE**
>  **DRIVE** → **Ar**rive
>  The 2011 Ryan Gosling movie, [**DRIVE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_(2011_film))

Comment: That is correct! I wish I could separate that checkmark in two to give Rand al'Thor more credit, his work did help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I'd written up a **partial answer** to this last week, and then decided it wasn't enough to bother posting. As it's still unanswered several days later, let's give it a shot.

---

Hint 4 makes me more sure that I'm correct about the one category I found:

> words that can have OVER in front of them to form new words.

The words in this category are

> BOARD, CLOCK, SIZE, TAKE, <s>TIME</s>.

---

Hint 3 could be

> words that can have HARD in front of them to form new words or phrases,

with the words being

> CANDY, DRUG, ROCK, TIME.

---

The remaining words, if I'm right about the two groups so far, are:

> ANON, CRAZY, DRUNK, MARCH, OAKEN, RAVEN, TOUCH, VAT.

Another category could be

> words that can have WOOD behind them,

because we have

> Ravenwood, Oakenwood, Marchwood, and the phrase "touch wood",

but I'm not sure which of the hints might be cluing that. If I'm right about this, it would leave

> ANON, CRAZY, DRUNK, VAT

as the last four words to be grouped somehow.

Comment: You're on the right way! Ubjrire GVZR vfa'g va gur "Bire" pngrtbel, rira gubhtu vg svgf.

Comment: I also suspected rot13(bire nf n pngrtbel), definitely seems most likely after hint 4. rot13("Bnxra") seems like it would be pretty easy to suss out but it has me stumped. I was thinking rot13("Bnxrafuvryq"), which is sort of validated by hint 2 but rot13("fuvryq") doesn't work on any other word. Maybe it's less straightforward?

Comment: @Auribouros Hmm, I can't figure out which of the others could fit in that category - [this](https://www.lexico.com/definition/overmarch) is "rare". For Hint 3, I was thinking about rot13(jbeqf gung pna or cerprqrq ol UNEQ) - TAKE, TIME, ROCK, CANDY perhaps - but it feels a bit tenuous.

Comment: @Randal'Thor could be rot13('birepybpx')?

Comment: @coffin_queen I was thinking of rot13(JBBQ - Bnxrajbbq naq Enirajbbq ner anzrf/cynprf, V guvax, naq gbhpu jbbq vf n cuenfr), but again it's a bit tenous, plus we need to find one word that could fit all four categories.

Comment: @Randal'Thor rot13(Znepujbbq vf nyfb n ivyyntr va Unzcfuver Ratynaq.) I think you might be onto something there.

Comment: I will continue posting daily hints. But I must say you're on the right way with one of those comments

Comment: @Auribouros OK, I've incorporated my comments into the answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Edited the question to clarify, the word that can fit in all categories is *not* in the grid, it's the word needed to find to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @Auribouros Ahh, that makes a big difference! I was restricting my search for categories to something that would also fit one of the four words in the first category I found.